# Rocket.Chat WebHook with Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, rocket.chat

im about to write a complex Incoming WebHook for Rocket.Chat. To avoid a mess in one single file i took Typescript. Rocket.Chat requires a class named `Script` with some predefined methods like `process_incoming_request` (one simple example: https://rocket.chat/docs/administrator-guides/integrations/).

my current project setup looks like:

**tsconfig.ts**

```
{
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "target": "es2015"
  }
}
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var browserify = require("browserify");
var source = require("vinyl-source-stream");
var tsify = require("tsify");
var uglify = require("gulp-uglify");
var buffer = require("vinyl-buffer");

gulp.task(
    "default",
    function () {
        return browserify({
            basedir: ".",
            debug: true,
            entries: ["src/main.ts"],
            cache: {},
            packageCache: {}
        })
            .plugin(tsify)
            .transform("babelify", {
                presets: ["es2015"],
                extensions: [".ts"]
            })
            .bundle()
            .pipe(source("bundle.js"))
            .pipe(buffer())
            .pipe(uglify())
            .pipe(gulp.dest("dist"));
    }
);
```

**main.ts**

```
import {RequestInterface} from "./Interface/RequestInterface";

class Script {
    process_incoming_request(request: RequestInterface) {
        // some code
    }
}
```

The `yarn gulp` process runs smoothly without errors but when using the generated code inside the script part of the webhook it results in an error:

```
Incoming WebHook.error script.js:1   
ReferenceError: module is not defined       
at script.js:1:4307       
at Script.runInContext (vm.js:127:20)       
at Script.runInNewContext (vm.js:133:17)       
at getIntegrationScript (app/integrations/server/api/api.js:70:12)       
at Object.executeIntegrationRest (app/integrations/server/api/api.js:166:13)       
at app/api/server/api.js:343:82       
at Meteor.EnvironmentVariable.EVp.withValue (packages/meteor.js:1234:12)       
at Object._internalRouteActionHandler [as action] (app/api/server/api.js:343:39)       
at Route.share.Route.Route._callEndpoint (packages/nimble_restivus/lib/route.coffee:150:32)       
at packages/nimble_restivus/lib/route.coffee:59:33
```

Im not that familiar with Typescript, Node and all the stuff. So the main question is, how can i achive that the process generates a class (or a script which exposes a class) named `Script` with the method `process_incoming_request`. Im also not sure if my script generates the error or the RocketChat part.

Thanks!

Comment: It would seem like there's some code you're not sending us that's causing the error. What's in your `script.js` file?

Comment: the `script.js` Error is thrown in the Rocket.Chat integration, it's not part of my script.

Comment: By _Rocket.Chat integration_ you mean the online editor of Rocket.Chat? Or do you have a serveur where you deploy your code?

Comment: Exactly the online editor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the problem is that Gulp (or some of it's plugins) generates a scaffolding code, necessary for JS's (non-existent) module system, and it often implies wrapping the compiler output into weird multi-layered anonymous functions.

If you don't need any kind of module system and just want your multiple TS files translated directly to a single JS file (which supposedly goes to the RocketChat), then I'd suggest ditching Gulp altogether, letting TSC to compile your code as usual, then bundling the resulting `.js` files into a single one with a script.

So, the overall setup would be as follows (assuming `src` is a source code folder):

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "target": "es2016"
  }
}
```

**build.sh**

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# TSC puts compiled JS files along with their TS sources. 
node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc

# Creating an empty bundle file.
echo "">dist/app.js

# Bundling all the JS together.
# sed removes the 'export' keywords & 'import' statements.
while read p; do
  cat $p | sed -E "s/^export\s+(class|function|async|const|var)/\1/" | sed -E "s/import.*$//" >> dist/app.js
done <<< $(find src -type f -name "*.js")
```

So you program your thing as usual, build it with `./build.sh`, get the `dist/app.js` file and use it in RocketChat.

There must be a way to do something along these lines in Gulp, but I'm not familiar with it, and don't think a full-blown build system is really needed here.

Comment: Nice idea, i'll give it a try later! Thank you.

Comment: sorry for the late response .. basically its working fine. Do you have any idea how to get rid of the export and import statement? [Example](https://pastebin.com/decwqpUu)

Comment: Unfortunately, no way to compile TS without `export`s, but it is possible to strip them during bundling. I updated the build script to remove export statements, but beware of multiline string literals - if there is a line which begins with `export class yada yada` in your string, it will be removed as well. Sed has no idea about JS.